# Find the second rank tensor that satisfies the identity.

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, tensors

I was given the following problem to consider:

Find the rank II tensor T that satisfies the identity,

$T - Tr(T)\delta = \delta\times\vec{a}$

No information was given for the vector $a$, so we assume it's an arbitrary vector.

The right-hand side of the equation is a vector product between a rank 2 tensor and a vector, but I think since we're working in three dimensions, we can write it as:

$T = Tr(T)\delta_{jk} -\delta_{jm}\epsilon_{mkn}a_n$

I am, unfortunately, stuck at this point. I've tried shuffling around with indices, but I didn't manage to do anything of notice.

Any help or tips are appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the skew-symmetric matrix 
$$\eqalign{
A &= -\varepsilon\cdot a &= I\times a \cr
A^T &= +\varepsilon\cdot a &= -A \cr
}$$
and calculate its trace
$$\eqalign{
{\rm tr}(A) &= A:I = A^T:I^T = -A:I = -{\rm tr}(A) \cr
{\rm tr}(A) &= 0 \cr
}$$
Therefore $\,T=A\,$ is a solution to the problem.

**NB:** In matrix notation, a colon denotes the double-dot product, i.e.
$$A:B = A_{ij}B_{ij}$$